# getting 403(Access Forbidden) error while accessing the site through browser

Tags: linux, apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Hi I'm getting 403 error while im accessing my live site through the browser. It was working fine last day. I'm not sure why this error is coming. I have searched a lot about it. These are the solutions I have tried:

1. I have changed my httpd.conf file's configurations from default to :

   `<Directory />
       #Options FollowSymLinks
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes
       AllowOverride All
       Order deny,allow
       Allow from all
   </Directory>`
2. Changed the permission for `/var/www/html` directory from default to `777`

and few more things. But nothing worked. I am not sure what is going wrong.

My server configurations are:

Apache/2.2.29.
AWS EC2 Instance.

This is the Error message shown on browser:

## forbidden

```
You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

This is the Error message from `error_logs`:

```
[Thu May 21 14:58:51 2015] [error] [client XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX] Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /var/www/
[Thu May 21 14:58:51 2015] [error] [client XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX] File does not exist: /var/www/error/noindex.html
```

please let me know in comments if you need anything else. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Do you have an index.html file in your DocumentRoot dir? Show your virtualhost config.

Comment: No, there is no index.html at /var/www (this is what i have set as DocumentRoot in httpd.conf file). I am not using any virtual hosts yet.

Comment: Basically it should show default apache page but its giving the above mentioned error.

Comment: If your DocumentRoot is '/var/www/', you should have enough permissions to read this folder instead of '/var/www/html', mentioned above. This directory must contain an index file or 'Index' option enabled.

Comment: Yes, it was looking for this index.html page. I created an dummy index.html page to check and it worked like charm. Thanks @umka

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was trying to set up vhost for Apache/2.2.29. AWS EC2 Instance.
meet same error . 
I solve it by looking the error.log

I need to give 755 to the parent folder

in your error log " File does not exist: /var/www/error/noindex.html" 
means you need to have this folder and the file.

what I use is  `chmod 755 -R /var/www/`

Answer (score 0):

You can try following steps:

1. In httpd.conf file Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews +Includes
2. Run on terminal: chown -R apache:apache /var/www/html
3. Restart Apache

Answer (score 0):

SE Linux sets security context label to every file. If there is an error setting the security context label the system throws forbidden error. 
Using "restorecon -v R" along with path name of the file's directory can clear the forbidden error.
The "restorecon" command restores the default security context to the file.